# Which Google AJAX API Key do I use in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-ajax

I would like to use some of the Google AJAX APIs in my Chrome extension, 
and I'm not sure if this is possible.

The AJAX API documentation clearly states that I must use a key that matches my domain. What would that be in case of an extension? My tests seem to work, but I;m worried this is only because I'm making a very small number of requests?

Is it possible? Which key should I be using?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just pointed to http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/key.html

"You do not need a key to use this API. Using a key in your application/site is completely optional."

So, I guess the answer is no key is needed.